# Required Many-to-Many field problem with API

Tags: content-management-system, directus

I am wondering if there is a way to create an item in a collection through the API, when that collection has a required Many-to-Many field.

Right now my process for creating an item with the API is to create the item with all regular fields, and then after the create I use the item's ID to create the values in the Many-to-Many field's collection.

However that create item API call fails when that M-M field is required, because there is no value set for that field.

Is there a way to create a collection item, and its many-to-many relationships in a single API call? Or some other workaround?